# Why does Kotlin allow non-null values to be typed as nullable, but then treats them as non-null anyway?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable

While I was trying to understand another issue, I ended up with the following code:

```
class WorkoutHistory(
    history: Map<Workout, Int> = EnumMap(Workout::class.java)
) {

    private val history: EnumMap<Workout, Int> = EnumMap(history)

    init {
        history.forEach { (workout: Workout, reps: Int?) ->
            doSomething(workout, reps)
        }
    }

    private fun doSomething(workout: Workout, reps: Int) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The code itself is not useful as I didn't understand that `forEach` will only iterate over values that are present, but it compiles and runs perfectly fine, and without any warning from Android Studio. I'm confused that the compiler allows me to give a nullable type to the non-null value `reps`, and then treats it as non-null anyway in the `doSomething` function which requires a non-null type.

Is this just an oversight or a deliberate behavior?

Comment: I guess it's because history is of type `EnumMap<Workout, Int>`. It's therefore smart enough to know that `reps` can never be `null`. If you change the type to `EnumMap<Workout, Int?>` it probably won't work

Comment: @Ivo that's the only explanation I can think of but it's strange that it's allowed at all

Comment: Android Studio is supposed to highlight the nullable `?` mark next to `Int`because it can never be null, the nullability indicator is therefore redundant. By `redundant`, I mean it _can_ be removed, but not necessarily, since it compiles just fine and has no impact whatsoever.

Another reason is because the end compiled bytecode result from this Kotlin code is completely different. Nulls in Kotlin are not like Swift's Optionals.